# Two console program reading content from same file in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, system.io.file

I have written console application for reading file content(file has located on sharing network).
File opened as read mode and also given Permission as you can see below,

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);            
var E51300Index = reader.ReadLine();
```

Then this console application installed on multiple machines(shared network) and trying to access at same time from different machine.

Parallel access not allowing and its throwing below error,

```
Process cannot access the file
xxx.txt because it is being used by another process
```

Is there any solution to file does not lock/parallel access.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Is a third process writing to the file?

Comment: How did you create that file?  Anything looking into it, like Visual Studio maybe?  NotePad[++] ?

Comment: @mjwills a static file placed on shared network, my console app reading that file only.

Comment: You definitely CAN read one file from multiple apps. So, it looks like something is writing to file, and this write will throw exception at anything that try read or write to file.